# How to use tracepoints in Kernel Module

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, bpf, tracepoint

I have started to learn these things recently. Regarding this matter, I came across plenty of resources regarding kprobes, BPF, eBPF, tracepoints and perf.

I wanted to test some irq events in the kernel (before it arrived to the device driver). Thus, I created a trace event in the kernel in the do_IRQ() function.

I have declared my tracepoint in the Kernel as:

```
TRACE_EVENT(vector_irq_rcv,

        TP_PROTO(unsigned int vector, unsigned int irq),

        TP_ARGS(vector, irq),

        TP_STRUCT__entry(
                __field(    unsigned int, vector    )
                __field(    unsigned int, irq       )
        ),

        TP_fast_assign(
                __entry->vector     =   vector;
                __entry->irq        =   irq;
        ),

        TP_printk("irq=%u cpu=%u",
                __entry->irq, __entry->vector)
);
```

To check this, I tried the following snippet with eBPF.

```
...

bpf_text = """
#include <linux/netdevice.h>
#include <uapi/linux/ptrace.h>

typedef struct my_stats {
    u32 irq;
    u32 ts;
} my_stat;

BPF_HASH(irq_rcv_stats, u32, my_stat);

TRACEPOINT_PROBE(irq_vectors, vector_irq_rcv) {

    if(!(args->irq == 65)) return 0;

    u32 pid = bpf_get_current_pid_tgid();
    my_stat val = {};
    val.ts = bpf_ktime_get_ns();
    val.irq = args->irq;
    irq_rcv_stats.update(&pid, &val);

    // bpf_trace_printk("IRQ %d encountered ; Vector = %d \\n", args->irq, args->vector);
    return 0;
}
"""
...
```

Here, I am listening for IRQ events on a particular IRQ number. This works well for me, for the time being.

Now, I was trying to attach this tracepoint in a kernel module (just the way we attach a kprobe in the kernel module). Is that even possible? 
At the moment, I have used perf for this, but it created some jitter. As I was evaluating some jitter sensitive tasks, I was hoping that I could use this tracepoint in the Kernel module.

I would appreciate any inputs or suggestions on this matter.

Thanks,
Cooshal.

Comment: Why do you want to use a kernel module if you already yave a working proof of concept with eBPF?

Comment: well, one reason was that I was not that familiar with BPF syntax. Additionally, how can I save these logs into a text file or csv or something like that?

Comment: See [this bcc tutorial](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/docs/tutorial_bcc_python_developer.md) for Linux tracing. In particular, Lesson 7 contains an example of how to retrieve data from the kernel in userspace, which you can then save to a file. In addition, there are [examples](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.1/source/samples/tracepoints/tracepoint-probe-sample.c) in the kernel's source code of tracepoint modules. Is there something specific you'd like to do in BPF that I can demonstrate? I can add an example of saving to a log file otherwise, if that's useful.

Comment: thank you for your response. I have updated the code snippet. I wanted to write the contents of **irq_rcv_stats** into a log file so that I can use it to calculate jitters later on.

Comment: @pchaigno I have a question regarding the [example](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.1/source/samples/tracepoints/tracepoint-probe-sample.c). Based on my code, what should I replace `register_trace_subsys_event` with? is it `register_trace_vector_irq_rcv` ? I tried it. I get a declaration error. Please let me know if I am doiing it the wrong way.